# bash uses wrong character length for multi-byte characters

Tags: bash, character-encoding

Sometimes I have a typo in a bash command line like in

```
> ls foo.cö
ls: cannot access 'foo.c'$'\303\266': No such file or directory
```

What I am doing then is to type `<up>` to get that command line from the history and edit it, i.e. remove the `ö` by typing a backspace.  This deletes the `ö` but I am getting:

```
> ls foo.c
ls: cannot access 'foo.c'$'\303': No such file or directory
```

What would work is to use two backspaces, which gives the non-intuitive correct result:

```
> ls foo.
foo.c
```

Is there any way so that the backspace will delete all of the umlaut, not only half of its encoding?

What would also be nice is if the diagnostic would print the correct argument, like `ls: cannot access 'foo.cö': No such file or directory`.

---

FYI, `locale` prints

```
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=de_DE
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Exporting `LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8` has no effect, and what I don't want to set other variables to other values because I don't know unwanted side-effects of that.

Comment: Any program that uses the variables likely know how to deal with UTF-8. Try setting the other ones before worrying about unwanted side effects.

Comment: try `export LANG=C.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C` locale does *not* support umlauts. Use one of the unicode locales such as `C.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8`: `LANG='C.UTF-8'`