# Using `LANG=C` with UTF-8 charset in bash

Tags: bash, utf-8, internationalization, customization

In order to handle special characters like (typo with) umlauts correctly, I am using `LANG=C.UTF-8` in my `.bashrc` as explained in [*"bash uses wrong character length for multi-byte characters"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75978109/1556746).

Now the problem is, that `LANG=C.UTF-8` picks a different default language like `LANG=C`.  What I want is to disable national language support so it's easier to search and talk about diagnostics:

```
> ls x
ls: Zugriff auf 'x' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

but want I want is original english diagnostic:

```
> LANG=C ls x
ls: cannot access 'x': No such file or directory
```

But using `LANG=C` in my `.bashrc` would unset UTF-8 charset, to I would be back where I started with *"bash uses wrong character length for multi-byte characters"*.

Is there a way to combine `LANG=C` with UTF-8? What obviously does not work is `LANG=C.UTF-8`.

### Edit 1

What does not work as expected:

```py
> LANG=C ls fö # In English but not UTF-8.
ls: cannot access 'f'$'\303\266': No such file or directory
```

```py
> LANG=C.UTF-8 ls fö # UFT-8 but not English. Same with C.utf8.
ls: Zugriff auf 'fö' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

```py
>  LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 ls fö # UTF-8 but not English; same with en_GB.utf8.
ls: Zugriff auf 'fö' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

```py
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ls fö #UTF-8 but not English; same with en_US.utf8.
ls: Zugriff auf 'fö' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

### Edit 2

Output of

```
> locale -a
C
C.utf8
POSIX
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_IT.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*LANG=C.UTF-8 picks a different default language*"? C.UTF-8 is C with UTF-8 encoding. No further changes. Else you may have a broken C.UTF-8 (check with `locale -a` if your system has it (some old systems may use different notation of locale (e.g. without dash, etc.)

Comment: Or just try `C`. (One of my most upvoted answers was about the need of `C.UTF-8` compared to `C`, but not many `C` locales (so many modern distributions) handles UTF-8 without problems (POSIX just requires that the "ASCII" part should match the standard behaviour, and UTF-8 encoding allow this; and not nobody will confuse char> 127 as Latin1, so a default UTF-8 in C is good [but not portable if you assume such behaviour on all systems])

Comment: You can see the effect with the error messages I posted. With `LANG=C` as of `.bashrc`,, the message is in english but it's not UTF-8. With `LANG=C.UTF-8` it's UTF-8 but in german again.

Comment: The version of LANG=C seems UTF-8 (but with your text we cannot tell: ASCII is a valid subset of UTF-8). Which operating system? Which glibc version? What do you get with `locale -a`?. With your edit: I get `ls: cannot access 'fö': No such file or directory` with both `LANG=C` and `C.UTF-8` on the latest stable Debian.

Comment: I added some examples to the question of what happens with `C`, with `C.UTF-8` and with `en_GB.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8`. Also added output of `locale -a`.

Comment: Did you try with `LANG=C.utf8 ls fö` ? It seems your system do not have `C.UTF-8` (and so I assume `C` is using the old ASCII only behaviour

Comment: `C.utf8` behaves like `C.UTF-8`; added to "Edit 1" section of the questio accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253428/discussion-between-giacomo-catenazzi-and-emacs-drives-me-nuts).